# Passing data between templates in django?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-registration

I'm creating a website that uses registration sort of like twitter where there is a pre-registration form that leads to another full registration form. Initially, I tried this using a POST and it worked but I realized the data from the first form could be seen through a proxy which I do not want.

I then did a proxy with Twitter's website and they use a GET instead of a POST. I'm thinking maybe I could do something using the session variables but not sure how to go about that or if I can do it with a GET. What would be the best approach for doing this with django?

Comment: are you using the django-registration package?

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are a good way to do that.  When processing the first form put the data in the session and retrieve it when processing the get.  Here's the documentation on Django sessions: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/sessions/